# Bug in IDL parser in RedHawk IDE

Tags: eclipse-plugin, corba, idl, redhawksdr

Some valid IDL files, build as IDL Projects and install but some or all of their contents do not appear in the SCA Explorer/Target SDR/IDL Repository.   I believe that the IDL parser used to build the tree in the IDL Repository is different from that used by the omniORB idl2cpp (omniidl) during building and it rejects some valid IDL.  The cases I have found all use a value of a const previously defined. e.g.,

const Algorithm ALG_NONE = 0
const Algorithm ALG_LPC = ALG_NONE + 3

The second line can occur in the same file or in a file that includes the file containing the first line.

The file containing the first line is accepted if the second line is not in the same file, but the file containing the second line is rejected and none of its contents appear in the IDL Repository tree.   It appears that it rejects a const appearing as a value on the right side of an assignment statement.  These files however are valid and are accepted as valid by omniidl.  But they cannot be used in RedHawk because they cannot be selected for a component interface.

I am not very familiar with RedHawk IDE sources or Eclipse plugins and so have not been able to find where the syntax for the parser is specified.  I see "eclipsecorba" appearing in plugin lists so I assume that RedHawk is using the Eclipse CORBA Plugin (aka ECP) and that its parser is the one being used to build the tree.  So I suspect that the parser error is in that package rather than in code added by RedHawk.

Can anyone confirm this and suggest where I might look in the ECP code for this?  Should I report this as a ECP bug to the ECP group on SourceForge?  I am not sure how active it is since it appears that the latest version is from 2008.

Comment: Here is a even case with base types:
module Test
{
 interface Bug {
    const long base = 0;
    // const long next = base + 1; // rejected
    const long next = 1;
    const long another = 1 + 2; //ok
    // const long base2 = base; //rejected
    };
  
};
Here is a even case with base types:

module Test
{
 interface Bug {
    const long base = 0;
    // this following builds but is rejected by IDE parser
    // const long next = base + 1;
    const long next = 1;
    const long another = 1 + 2;
    // and this is rejected
    // const long base2 = base;
    };
  
};

Comment: sorry.  I still cannot get line breaks.Here is a even case with base types:  

module Test  
{  
 interface Bug {  
    const long base = 0;  
    // this following builds but is rejected by IDE parser  
    // const long next = base + 1;  
    const long next = 1;  
    const long another = 1 + 2;  
    // and this is rejected  
    // const long base2 = base;  
    };
  
};

Comment: See response on this thread: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/34133411/1311595](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34133411/1311595).

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in the IDL editor, the IDL you have is legal. Would recommend you to report this to ECP but given the long inactivity of that project probably it will not fixed soon. I do know that one of our [Remedy IT](http://www.remedy.nl) engineers has created a more modern IDL editor for Eclipse but due to lack of funding this work is not available publicly.