# which plugin does RedHawk 1.10 use for IDL editing

Tags: redhawksdr

RedHawk installs JARs for eclipse plugins from redhawk-yum-1.10.2-5-el6-x86_64.tar.gz.  In RedHawk 1.9 it only installed 4 JARs for IDL parsing and editing, but in RedHawk 1.10 it installs these 4 but also 2 from Eclipse Corba Package.

```
gov.redhawk.eclipsecorba.idl_7.1.0.201501292343.jar
gov.redhawk.eclipsecorba.idl.source_7.1.0.201501292343.jar
gov.redhawk.eclipsecorba.idl.edit_4.1.0.201501292343.jar
gov.redhawk.eclipsecorba.idl.edit.source_4.1.0.201501292343.jar
net.sf.eclipsecorba.idl_0.7.0.218.jar
net.sf.eclipsecorba.idl.edit_0.7.0.218.jar
```

Many java files have the same names but there are also many differences.
From comments in the source java files it appears that the gov jars used JavaCC to build the parser while those from ECP used SableCC.

Which ones are actually used in RedHawk 1.10 or are they both used for different purposes?

I am trying to look into a parser bug and would like to know which parser to look at.

Sorry, I am not familiar with Eclipse plugin development and have not figured out how to tell what plugins are actually loaded or how they are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redhawk uses the Eclipse Corba Plugin (ECP) project to provide an editor for IDL files:

http://eclipsecorba.sourceforge.net/

The editor does not support constant IDL expresions (e.g. const foo = bar + 1). Unfortunately, the project is not maintained any more (last release in 2008).

For all other IDL functions in the IDE, such as displaying IDLs under the "Target SDR" in the explorer view, the Redhawk IDE has its own parser code which handles this. The IDE's parser currently has the same limitation - it does not recognize constant IDL expressions.

Comment: I continued looking into this after I posted this question and find that starting with RH1,10, the IDL editor DOES use ECP but the code building the IDL Repository tree for Target SDR (allowing selecting an interface) continues to use the parser used in 1.9 and before which is in gov.redhawk.eclipsecorba.idl.*  and is based on the JavaCC compiler-compiler while ECP uses SableCC.  Surprisingly BOTH have the same bug in handling const expressions even though their parser grammar DOES accept them.

Answer (score 0):

RedHawk uses three distinct IDL parsers. 1) omnicpp (omniorbs version of idl2cpp) uses its own parser. 2) the code that builds a tree for the IDL Repository in Target SDR uses a plugin in gov.redhawk.eclipsecorba.idl.* which has a parser based on JavaCC compiler-compiler. 3) the IDL editor that was introduced in RedHawk 1.9 uses a different plugin in net.sf.eclipsecorba.idl.* which as a parser based on SableCC, a different compiler-compiler.